# Moment.js formatting "Date(2021,0,1)"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm working with moment.js and need help converting the following string:

```
let dtString = "Date(2021,0,1)";
let dt = moment(dtString, 'YYYY,M,D').format('l');
```

`"Date(2021,0,1)"` has a zero based month.  The code above returns invalid date.

When I try `"Date(2021,1,1)"`, `dt` returns 1/1/2021.

How can I get moment to recognize that the `M` value is a zero based month and return `"Date(2021,0,1)"` as 1/1/2021?

UPDATE:
Here's something else I just tried...again it's clunky but works.

```js
let dtString = "Date(2021,0,1)";
let dtArray = dtString.replace("Date(", "").replace(")", "").split(",").map(Number);
let jsDate = new Date(dtArray[0], dtArray[1], dtArray[2]);
let dt = moment(jsDate).format('l');
console.log(dt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE 2:
Combining @kometen and @eskew I've found that this also works.  Thank you to both!

```js
let dtString = "Date(2021,0,1)";
let dtArray = dtString.replace("Date(", "").replace(")", "").split(",").map(Number);
let dt = moment(dtArray).format('l');
console.log(dt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Certainly outside the scope of the question as you've posed it, but to satisfy my own curiosity, where's `dtString` coming from that it outputs zero-indexed month values like this?

Comment: @esqew it looks almost like this was JS code to begin with (part of `new Date(2021,0,1)` or something?), which would beg the question, why they are trying to feed _that_ into the moment constructor to begin with.

Comment: _“How can I get moment to recognize that the M value is a zero based month and return "Date(2021,0,1)" as 1/1/2021?”_ - instead of letting it guess what the - rather arbitrary seeming – stuff you feed into it _could_ be supposed to mean, you can _specify_ the format. https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/ (You might still have to strip off the `Date(` and `)` though, I can’t currently see whether moment allows to define “placeholders” for stuff to ignore.)

Comment: Hi, our API returns "Date(2021,0,1)" because later in the program this string is used in a Google Visualization table.  GV knows to convert it to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One slightly clunky way of doing this would be to parse `dtString` into its parts and then reassemble them in the [`moment()` constructor's parameter in an array structure](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/), which will tell momentjs to parse them in the same way the native `Date` API would (including zero-indexed month values, among others):

```js
let dtString = "Date(2021,0,1)";
let dtStringFormat = /Date\((?<Year>\d{4}),(?<Month>\d{1,2}),(?<Day>\d{1,2})\)/g;
let groups = dtStringFormat.exec(dtString).groups;
let dt = moment(Object.values(groups));
console.dir(dt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I just added an update.  I started with your idea of parsing it into pieces and reassembling.  It's a bit different but accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: It looks like I'm forced to take the "clunky" approach with this one.  My JavaScript experience is medium so I always ask advice on best practice from experts.  Do you see a speed difference between your way and mine?

Comment: @cmill A good question best answered using a utility like [JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me) - I've set up the cases [here](https://jsbench.me/uckljmf8b7) for you to run in your local setup. Once run, it will show you which method is faster in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like moment().month() does [accept](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) 0-based month-numbering so if you change it to `moment([2012, 0, 31])` it should work.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the idea!  I've posted it in Update 2 along with a suggestion from @eskew.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer. I neither recommend or endorse using `eval` as it can be abused.

Having said that, if you can trust the date string is not going to include anything dangerous than you could use it like so. No parsing required.

```js
let dtString = "Date(2021,0,1)";
let date = eval('new ' + dtString);
let dt = moment(date).format('l');

document.getElementById('date').innerText = dt;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: Originally, I used this method.  I don't like using `eval()` either even though I do trust that nothing besides `"Date(2021,0,1)"` will be sent into it.   Thank you for the reply.  I value everyone's comments greatly.